# CD/DVD drive won't eject media - Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, cd-drive

I have an older Gateway computer with a CD writer/DVD player installed, and I just started using Kubuntu 12.04. After I insert a CD or DVD, I'm unable to eject it with the button on the drive. It sounds like it's spinning in there without stopping even though I'm not running the disk in a program. The only way I seem to be able to remove it is by restarting the computer and removing the disk as the computer boots up. I've been running standard Ubuntu 12.04 on this computer until recently, and never had this issue. Any thoughts? Thanks!

P.S. I just entered the command "eject" in the terminal, and it properly ejected the DVD media. However, after closing the tray, it won't reopen, so I entered the same command a second time, and received this response:

john-hill@Gateway-E-4100:~$ eject
eject: unable to eject, last error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
john-hill@Gateway-E-4100:~$

Or maybe it's supposed to respond to that command like that, since there's no media in the drive?

Comment: Type "eject" then immediately pry open the tray with a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be already reported Bug #875543 : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/875543

i would suggest to watch this topic and see if solution appears - now its confirmed as a Bug.